# How to lineup a multirow in a table?

Tags: tables

I am making a table with multirow in it but the rows in last column are far from each other. How to fix it?

My code is:

```
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx,booktabs,parskip,setspace,amsmath,amssymb,multirow}
    \begin{table} [ht]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{The range of the ratios of hydrophyte evapotranspiration to open water evaporation}
    \centering
    \label{tab:2.1}
    \begin{tabular}{c p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} r} 
    \toprule%
    No & Author & Country & Plant type & Method & $ET_h/E_w$ \\
    \hline

        \multirow{2}{*}{8.} & Snyder and Boyd (1987) & Alabama, USA & \textit{Eichhornia crassipes, Typha latifolia} & Tanks & 1.3-2.5 \\
        & & & & & 1.05-2.5\
```

After compiling I have last column with multirows: 1.3-2.5 and 1.05-2.5 far from each other. I want the rows to be close to each other, at least the row with 1.05-2.5 to have opposite to Typha latifolia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can put everything in a single row by suitably adjusting the column width in `p{...}.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx,booktabs,parskip,setspace,amsmath,amssymb,multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{The range of the ratios of hydrophyte evapotranspiration to open water evaporation}
    \centering
    \label{tab:2.1}
    \begin{tabular}{c p{2cm} p{2cm} p{3.2cm} p{2cm} R}
    \toprule%
    No & Author & Country & Plant type & Method & $ET_h/E_w$ \\
    \midrule
    \raisebox{-1ex}{8.} & Snyder and Boyd (1987) & Alabama, USA & \textit{Eichhornia crassipes Typha latifolia} & 
    \raisebox{-1ex}{Tanks} & 1.3--2.5 1.05--2.5 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of using `\hline`, you can use `\midrule` from `booktabs`.

Comment: Many thanks, I see the difference. It looks great!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are confused regarding the use of `multirow`. It is used for material that spans more than one row of the table (on some column), not for material that occupies more than one line of text.

I think that what you want can simply be achieved by putting *Typha latifolia* and *1.05-2.5* on their own row:

```
    8. & Snyder and Boyd (1987) & Alabama, USA & \textit{Eichhornia crassipes} & Tanks & 1.3-2.5 \\
       &                        &              & \textit{Typha latifolia}      &       & 1.05-2.5\
```

As an aside, do consider using `--` instead of `-` for ranges: `1.05--2.5`.

Comment: Thank you, how simple! And thanks for the advise about ranges --

Comment: You can only accept one answer: the one you prefer most, the one that came first if more are equivalent etc. I think you can change your mind after you have accepted one answer. Moreover, you can up-vote as many answers as you wish.

Comment: Thank you. But only after I have 15 reputation I can up-vote answers.